# REST call returns 404 not found

Tags: java, rest, maven, tomcat, jersey

I am having an issue regarding a rest call I want to make from my app. I am using Tomcat 7 with Jersey.

This is how my pom.xml looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>JavaWeb</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>JavaWeb Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>JavaWeb</finalName>

  <plugins>
            <!-- Eclipse project -->
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                    <!-- Always download and attach dependencies source code -->
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                <!-- Avoid type mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0 -->
                <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>

          <!-- Set JDK Compiler Level -->
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>

          <!-- For Maven Tomcat Plugin -->
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <path>/JavaWeb</path>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>

        </plugins>
          </build>
</project>
```

My web.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>


<!-- .. -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>

    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>
         <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>demo.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

This is my class where I have my service. I rewrote it to match the hello example, to see what am I doing wrong but it does not work this way either:

```
    @Path("/hello")
    public class VehicleRest {

      // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
      @GET
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
      public String sayPlainTextHello() {
        return "Hello Jersey";
      }

      // This method is called if XML is request
      @GET
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
      public String sayXMLHello() {
        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
      }

      // This method is called if HTML is request
      @GET
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
      public String sayHtmlHello() {
        return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
            + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
      }

}
```

I am trying to access it like this in my browser: `http://localhost:8081/JavaWeb/rest/hello`
My class where I have my path declared it is found, when I run the server, so I don't think that is the problem. Maybe there is an issue with the Jersey config. I looked up other questions and answers also, but nothing helped me. Would it help if I made the configuration again and downloaded the jersey jars again ? It just gives me 404 not found when I am trying to access that URI.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1 question:
You wrote  `@Path("/hello")` at class level. How will your controller know which method to execute with the URL you are trying to hit?

Are you sure of what `@Produces` does? It should not be `@Consumes`?

Comment: You might have to change "Produces" to "Consumes".

Comment: For GET-Requests it is okay to route to the method that @Produces what the clients accepts in its Accept-Header...

Comment: I suspect this works. Maybe just doublecheck the port, or remove `/JavaWeb` from the Url.